Gotten partway there but stuck on finding the min/max of a sinusoidal
I think I've gotten partway there but now I'm stuck. I'm trying to find the min and/or max points of
$$y=\frac{1}{2}\sin⁡(2x)+3\cos⁡(x)+x$$ in the interval of $0<x<2\pi$.
This is what I've got so far:
$$\begin{align}
y'&=\frac{1}{2}\cos⁡(2x)(2)+3\cos⁡(x)+1\\
&=\cos⁡(2x)-3\sin⁡(x)+1\\
&=1-2\sin^2(2x)-3\sin⁡(x)+1\\
&=-2\sin^2(2x)-3\sin⁡(x)+2
\end{align}$$
I can see that it's looking like a polynomial and how it would factor to then be able to find the critical numbers if it were possible, but I don't know what the do with the $2x$. It feels like I could just go around in circles with the angle addition identities. Am I on the right track or no?

Welcome to Math SE. Note that $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(\color{red}{x})$ (e.g., as shown in Wikipedia's trigonometric Double-angle formulae section), while you have $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(\color{red}{2x})$ instead.

You are on the right track, but you have a small mistake going from line 2 to line 3: $$\cos(2x) = 1-2\sin^2(x).$$
So in the end you should have $$y' = -2\sin^2(x) - 3\sin(x) + 2.$$
From there, as you say, you can turn it into a polynomial to solve.
Edit: also, don't forget that this method is only good for finding local extrema which are stationary points. Depending on the specific question you may also need to consider where there might be any global extrema that are not stationary points.
